# Reading data from S3 using Lambda

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a range of json files stored in an S3 bucket on AWS.

I wish to use AWS lambda python service to parse this json and send the parsed results to an AWS RDS MySQL database.

I have a stable python script for doing the parsing and writing to the database. I need to lambda script to iterate through the json files (when they are added).

Each json file contains a list, simple consisting of `results = [content]`

In pseudo-code what I want is:

1. Connect to the S3 bucket (`jsondata`)
2. Read the contents of the JSON file (`results`)
3. Execute my script for this data (`results`)

I can list the buckets I have by:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name)
```

Giving:

```
jsondata
```

But I cannot access this bucket to read its results.

There doesn't appear to be a `read` or `load` function.

I wish for something like

```
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
   print(bucket.contents)
```

EDIT

I am misunderstanding something. Rather than reading the file in S3, lambda must download it itself.

From [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-walkthrough-s3-events-adminuser-create-test-function-create-function.html) it seems that you must give lambda a download path, from which it can access the files itself

```
import libraries

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def function to be executed:
   blah blah

def handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key'] 
        download_path = '/tmp/{}{}'.format(uuid.uuid4(), key)
        s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, download_path)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`bucket.objects.all()`](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=list#S3.Bucket.objects) to get a list of the all objects in the bucket (you also have alternative methods like `filter`, `page_size`and `limit` depending on your need)

These methods return an iterator with [`S3.ObjectSummary`](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=s3.objectsummary#S3.ObjectSummary)  objects in it, from there you can use the method `object.get` to retrieve the file.

Answer (score 53):

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
emailcontent = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Should also note that you need to create an s3 object to use in your response. i.e. `s3 = boto3.client('s3')`